# HP Laptop won't boot into Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I turned my laptop off with a hard button press while it was trying to hibernate and now it won't boot up into Windows 7 (x64).  I get a blue screen with the following information:

> UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME
>   Stop Code 0x000000ED

I have also tried booting up in safe mode but it hangs on the classpnp.sys.

Can somebody provide a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This error indicates exactly what it says - the boot volume couldn't be mounted.  This may be due to file system corruption, a problem with the bootloader pointing at the incorrect partition, a problem with the physical connection to the drive, or even a problem with the drive itself mechanically.

My guess in this situation would be that your timing of the power down was lousy and your Windows partition has some problems.  See if you can run a chkdsk on it and maybe if you're lucky it'll be able to fix it for you.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem once. My laptop lost power while it was starting up, and it lost the file system. As Shinrai said, chkdsk may be able to fix it, but if not, there are many programs you can use to recover a hard drive. I can't remember which one I used, but they all do about the same thing. They look through the data on the hard drive for patterns, and use that to figure out where files are. All of your data is most likely still there, Windows just can't find it.

To run chkdsk on your system, you have a couple options. If you have a Windows disc, you can boot into that. Otherwise, download RC.ISO from [this page](http://www.thecomputerparamedic.com/index.php?view=article&catid=16%3Awindows-xp&id=18%3Arecovery-console-you-asked-for-it&tmpl=component&print=1&layout=default&page=&option=com_content&Itemid=29) and burn it to a CD. Note that this is not the same as burning a data file, you need to make sure you're burning the ISO as an image.

Once you have one of those, put it in the computer and boot from the disc. To do this, keep an eye on the bottom of the screen as it boots. Early in the boot, it will display `[key] for boot options` (On my HP computer, `[key]` is F9). Choose `Boot Device`, and select your CD drive. Once it boots, you will be able to choose `Recover Console`. You may need to log in at this point.

At the Recovery Console prompt, type in `chkdsk /r`. Let the chkdsk run uninterrupted until it completes. If it gives any errors, let us know. Once it finishes, type `exit`, and then press `Enter` to leave the Recovery Console and restart your computer.

Comment: +1 - I didn't bother explaining chkdsk because there are plenty of other sources on that.  As far as getting your data if it is in trouble, the easiest thing to do is to pull the drive and slave it to another machine.  Probably it'll work fine as a non-boot partition.  (This is also a pretty easy way to scan the disk in the first place.)

Comment: @Shinrai In my case, even that didn't work. The file system itself was shot. I had to use an external drive enclosure to hook it up to another computer and recover the data.

Comment: That would be what "slave it to another machine" meant.

Comment: @Shinrai Right, I was saying I couldn't just pull the files off, I had to run recovery software on it.

Comment: Oh, "recover" in the literal sense.  My bad.  Yeah, that's a definite possibility.

Comment: @SaintWacko: The RC.ISO BSOD on my windows7 laptop so I can't run it.  One thing that I'm running into is that the drive is bit lockered. (per my company and help desk/field services don't havea  clue and are pretty much useless)  I tried running repairs via the installation CD for win 7 but my bit locker key won't take and therefore I can't even run chkdsk.  I even tried running ubuntu live CD and I can't mount the damn drive because it's bit lockered and the partition shows up empty and gives me NTFS signature errors when trying to mount (again via ubuntu mount command).

Comment: Ooh, yeah, if it's bit lockered, nothing else is going to be able to recognize it as data unless it's been specifically designed to work with a bit lockered drive. When the data is encrypted, it appears as random bits to anything but bit locker :(

Comment: Yeah.  If this is encrypted and not backed up anywhere else you may be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for the inconvenience that is causing you but unfortunately, you corrupted your master boot record.
if you have a windows 7 DVD, not a restore disk you can try to repair it by running
a system check disk
here are some links to help you out.

[Unmountable_Boot_Volume STOP:0x000000ED](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-recovery-error-unmountablebootvolume/304fdb50-344f-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

[Bootrec.exe tool in the Windows Recovery Environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392)
good luck

Comment: if you don't have a windows 7 disk, you can borrow your friends [if he is near] or you can download Windows Bootable recovery Disk here is a link to many you can try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinBuilder. the best one that i remember a long time ago was http://www.ubcd4win.com/ but ever since i switch to linux i don't know which is best, you can also use linux distribution to do a windows check disk, but i would do that as last resort. good luck.

Comment: Will performing the following steps delete all data or just create a new bootable area?  bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
c:
cd boot
attrib bcd -s -h -r
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bootrec /RebuildBcd